# Make image-thumbnail in bootstrap adjacent to each other and identical in size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I am making a webpage in which I want to make 2 image thumbnails appear adjacent to each other with same height.
Consider my html code:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ym35iJI.jpg" alt="frontend" class="img-thumbnail" width="640px" height="480px">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ot6RubY.jpg" alt="webd" class="img-thumbnail" width="640px" height="480px">
    </div>
</div>
```

Corresponding to the given code in the output it shows(this is just a cropimage of the output) :

[image: output]

I cant see why the height attribute doesnt assign same height to both the images

As asked in one of the answers here is the css file:

```css
body{
 background-color: rgb(45,45,45);
}
.page-header{
 height: 100px;
 background-color: rgb(17, 17, 17);
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#title{
 font-size:400%;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.nav-button{
 margin-top:24px;
 margin-right:50px;
 margin-left:50px;
 width:110px;
 height:55px;  
 }

.btn h3{
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}

.about{
 background-color: rgb(175, 187, 206);
 height:300px;
 font-size:16px;
}

.container{
 margin-top:0px;
}


.body-text{
 font-family:'Cabin', sans-serif;
 padding-top:60px;
 padding-left:25px;
 font-size:175%;
}
.my-image{
 height:280px;
 width:270px;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-right:30px;
}


.portfolio{
 height: 1200px;
}

#portfolio-heading{
 padding-top: 30px;
 color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

Comment: simply i just see that you override the image height in your css. if you set width/height as styles tour img tags, it will be ok! `<img src="..." style='width:640px; height:480px;' />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using CSS:-

https://jsfiddle.net/Lrbw117q/1/

You can also put the background image inline if you need to.

```
#box1 {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/Ym35iJI.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

#box2 {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/ot6RubY.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.img-thumbnail {
  height: 640px;
  width: 480px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: so using this i can also change the border color of the thumbnail?

Answer (score 1):

I just placed your code into a fresh html file, and tested it. Both images are given the exact same height. I personally would check your stylesheet for any inconsistencies in any of the mentioned classes/IDs, or anything that could have affected its size.

You may want to check for your styling for a
    'height:auto;'
or the like.

My suggestion would be to put a 'overflow:hidden;' into your stylesheet "img-thumbnail" class.

To be able to successfully fix this for you, we would need to see more of your code.

Edit: Also, I may suggest that you check to see which of the divs is the incorrect height. In chrome, this can be done by inspecting element (right-click > inspect element), navigating to the code in question, and hovering over it. This should hopefully determine your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `flex` property try the demo

```css
.outer , .outer div {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="outer">  
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ym35iJI.jpg" alt="frontend" class="img-thumbnail" width="640px" height="480px">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ot6RubY.jpg" alt="webd" class="img-thumbnail" width="640px" height="480px">
    </div>
</div>  
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

The width and height attribute doesn't work on an image:

You should do this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ym35iJI.jpg" alt="frontend" class="img-thumbnail" style="widht: 640px; height:480px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ot6RubY.jpg" alt="webd" class="img-thumbnail" style="widht: 640px; height:480px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Better practice however is that make you own class:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="myClass" src="http://i.imgur.com/Ym35iJI.jpg" alt="frontend" class="img-thumbnail" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="myClass" src="http://i.imgur.com/ot6RubY.jpg" alt="webd" class="img-thumbnail" style="widht: 640px; height:480px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

And make a css-file with following code:

```
.myClass { 
  width: 640px; 
  height: 480px;
}
```

I however suggest the following thing. Make sure your images have the same size in advance using an editing tool (i.e. Photoshop) and use the default img-responsive class that comes standard with bootstrap.

This will make your website more responsive which is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use this code:

div.col-md-6 {
    height:400px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
}

img.img-thumbnail {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    min-height:100%;
    display:block;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    min-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ym35iJI.jpg" alt="frontend" class="img-thumbnail" style="height: 500px;background-size: cover;"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ot6RubY.jpg" alt="webd" class="img-thumbnail" style="height: 500px;background-size: cover;"/>
</div>
```